# Angular 2 - Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: System is not defined

Tags: angular, referenceerror

my english is poor, my apology for this :)

I have a problem with angular 2. I would create a login form but after call web service and get response I had this error below.

To blocked and authorized user on my app I'm based on auth-guard.service.ts of angular tutorial.

This error came after the canLoad action on my routing.

I use angular 2 latest version, my project is based on webpack.

My package.json configuration is :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^2.2.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
```

My error is :

```
core.umd.js?e2a5:3004 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: System is not defined
ReferenceError: System is not defined
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:7151:20)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:7144:64)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:253:2), <anonymous>:168:76)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:253:2), <anonymous>:160:52)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:253:2), <anonymous>:904:82)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:343:2), <anonymous>:110:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:343:2), <anonymous>:100:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at EverySubscriber.notifyComplete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:367:2), <anonymous>:47:26)
    at EverySubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:367:2), <anonymous>:64:14)
    at EverySubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:379:2), <anonymous>:94:30)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:132:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.complete (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:114:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:289:2), <anonymous>:116:24)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeAllOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:379:2), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at EveryOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:367:2), <anonymous>:27:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:343:2), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:343:2), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at CatchOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:391:2), <anonymous>:30:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:349:2), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:379:2), <anonymous>:85:42)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at MapSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:83:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at ArrayObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:289:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at ArrayObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeAllOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:379:2), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at FirstOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:403:2), <anonymous>:70:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at CatchOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:391:2), <anonymous>:30:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Object.subscribeToResult (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:349:2), <anonymous>:21:27)
    at MergeAllSubscriber._next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:379:2), <anonymous>:85:42)
    at MergeAllSubscriber.Subscriber.next (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:130:2), <anonymous>:89:18)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:295:2), <anonymous>:49:24)
    at ScalarObservable.Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:56:27)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeAllOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:379:2), <anonymous>:63:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at LastOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:415:2), <anonymous>:38:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at CatchOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:391:2), <anonymous>:30:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:343:2), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:373:2), <anonymous>:54:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:343:2), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at Observable._subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:114:28)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:343:2), <anonymous>:75:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:53:22)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:87:38)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:518:29)
    at Observable.forEach (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:112:2), <anonymous>:86:16)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:253:2), <anonymous>:2630:22)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:518:29)
    at Router.runNavigate (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:253:2), <anonymous>:2595:20)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:253:2), <anonymous>:2586:71)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:232:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6206:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:231:32)
    at Zone.run (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:114:43)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:502:57)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:265:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6197:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:264:40)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:154:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:401:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:339:25)
```

Have you a response for me ?

Comment: Do you have your system.js file referenced in your root html page?

`<script src="https://npmcdn.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>` for instance

Comment: ok, thanks I have add this :

<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>

Comment: That resolved the issue for you?

Comment: Yes, but now a new problem has emerged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is an underlying problem of [Angular 2 - Uncaught (in promise): Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501323/angular-2-uncaught-in-promise-error-xhr-error-404-not-found)

In webpack you do not need to add systemjs.

The real problem is an routing problem ... To solved this :

To use this router loader you must install it :

```
npm install angular2-router-loader -- save-dev
```

And you must implements 'angular2-router-loader' in your webpack config like this :

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader','angular2-router-loader']
      },
...
],
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Had the same problem. The following were key for me:</s>

Nevermind. I could have sworn it worked. When I use non-lazy routes my components load fine with Angular Universal. I had `{ path: 'lazy', component: LazyViewComponent }` instead of the lazy route, and I noticed my `RouterModule` in `lazy.module.ts` wasn't exported. So I tried the lazy route again, now with `RouterModule` exported, and I could have sworn it worked. I then removed `angular2-router-loader` to see if that was needed, and it was, and then tested if a local route for the module was needed, and it was. Shared my findings on the interwebs, came back to find it wasn't working. I guess let's just stick with non-lazy routes for now.

`webpack.config.js` should include **both `@ngtools/webpack` and `angular2-router-loader`**:

```js
const ngtools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/main.server.ts'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    modulesFromFile: true
  })],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new ngtools.AotPlugin({
      tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: [
          '@ngtools/webpack',
          'angular2-router-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }
    ]
  }
};
```

The routing module needs to use an **absolute path** to the module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeViewComponent } from './home-view/home-view.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeViewComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'lazy', loadChildren: 'app/lazy.module#LazyModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And crucially, the lazy module needs to **export the `RouterModule`**

```js
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'os-lazy-view',
  template: `<h3>i'm lazy</h3>`,
})
export class LazyViewComponent {
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [LazyViewComponent],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: LazyViewComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]),
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class LazyModule {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only to add  the property pathMatch: 'full' to your empty lazy-load route.Like below:

```
  {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: './modules/home-page/home-page.module#HomePageModule',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      data: {
       id: 'homePage'
      }
 }
```

Enjoy!

Omar