# Angular 2 - Uncaught (in promise): Error: XHR error (404 Not Found)

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

my english is poor, my apology for this :)

I have a problem with angular 2. I would create a login form but after call web service and get response I had this error below.

To blocked and authorized user on my app I'm based on auth-guard.service.ts of angular tutorial.

This error come after the canLoad action on my routing.

I use angular 2 latest version, my project is based on webpack.

My error :

```
core.umd.js?e2a5:3004 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9090/app/home/home.module
    Error loading http://localhost:9090/app/home/home.module
Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9090/app/home/home.module
    at o (https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js:4:12694)
    at XMLHttpRequest.I.s.onreadystatechange (https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js:4:13219)
    at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:698:29)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:265:35)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/vendor.js:100:2), <anonymous>:6197:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:264:40)
    at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:154:47)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:9090/polyfills.js:2195:2), <anonymous>:335:33)
```

If you have any solutions :)

Comment: you have created home.module.ts have you import that module in app.module file?

Comment: my home module is :

`import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';

import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }`

Comment: and my app.module :

`import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AuthRoutingModule,
    HomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AuthComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }`

Comment: I have write modifications to implements Home compoenent This solved the problem but my older problem come back :'(


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497167/angular-2-uncaught-in-promise-referenceerror-system-is-not-defined

Comment: I Have solved my problem ...

In the context of Webpack to use Router loadChidren You must implements  'angular2-router-loader' in your webpack config like this :

`loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader','angular2-router-loader']
      },`

And to use this router loader you must install it :

npm install angular2-router-loader — save-dev



I have see the solution on this website : 

https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-lazy-loading-with-webpack-d25fe71c29c1#.p5wy52jv1

Comment: nice bro just past your answer in down so other can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have solved my problem ...

In the context of Webpack to use Router loadChidren :

---> You must implements 'angular2-router-loader' in your webpack config like this :

```
loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader','angular2-router-loader']
      },
...
],
```

And, to use this router loader you must install it :

```
npm install angular2-router-loader -- save-dev
```

I have see the solution on this website :

https://medium.com/@daviddentoom/angular-2-lazy-loading-with-webpack-d25fe71c29c1#.p5wy52jv1

And, must not import child module  in parent module ;)